# Scrollable calender month view: title text of custom button in collection view gets overwritten

Tags: objective-c, calendar, uicollectionview

I want to create a custom, scrollable month view, in which the user is able to scroll through all months of the corresponding year (just like the iPad calendar).

So I created one array for all the date components I need. There are 12 subarrays in this array, one for each month. I already managed to fill my subarrays with the correct date components of the corresponding year.

[image]

I set the number of sections in my collectionView to be 12 (one for each month) and the items in my section to have the same number as the number of days in the current month.

In order to label my button titles within the collection view cell with the date components, I wrote this method to get the String for the title label:

```
- (NSString *)getDayOfMonthFromComponent: (NSDateComponents *)components{

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDate *newDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:self.currentDate options:0];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterDayOfMonth = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatterDayOfMonth setDateFormat:@"d"]; // filter day of month

    NSString *dayOfMonth = [dateFormatterDayOfMonth stringFromDate:newDate];
    return dayOfMonth;
}
```

That's how I label my custom button:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    EMMonthCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MonthCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    EMBorderlessButton *button;

#pragma mark - dateLabel sort algorithm iPhone

    if (IS_IPHONE){

#pragma mark - dateLabel sort algorithm iPad

    } else if (IS_IPAD){

        button = [[EMBorderlessButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 30, 30)];
        NSString *titleText;

        NSLog(@"index path: %ld of section: %ld", (long)indexPath.row, (long)indexPath.section);

        if (indexPath.row < [[self.daysThisMonthArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] intValue]){
            titleText = [self getDayOfMonthFromComponent:self.dateComponents [indexPath.section] [indexPath.row]];
        }

        [button setTitle:titleText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        [button setSelected:FALSE];
        [button setTag:indexPath.row];

        [cell addSubview:button];
        [self.buttonArray addObject:button];
        [cell bringSubviewToFront:button];

    }

    return cell;
}
```

The labeling basicly works, but as soon as I start scrolling, the titleLabels get overwritten. 
How can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance for your help.

[image: labeling failure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The solution was pretty simple: with interface builder I just dragged a button in my collection view cell and assigned it to my custom button class. I addition, I connected the created button as outlet to my custom collection view cell class.

Afterwards I changed the code like this:

```
#pragma mark - dateLabel sort algorithm iPad

    } else if (IS_IPAD){

        NSLog(@"check content: %@", self.daysThisMonthArray);
        EMBorderlessButton *theLabel = (EMBorderlessButton *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
        [theLabel setTitleColor:[UIColor em_darkViolett] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        if (indexPath.row < [[self.daysThisMonthArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] intValue]){
            [cell.dateButton setTitle:[self getDayOfMonthFromComponent:self.dateComponents [indexPath.section] [indexPath.row]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            if ([[self getDayOfMonthFromComponent:self.dateComponents [indexPath.section] [indexPath.row]] isEqualToString:@"1"]){
                [cell.dateButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@. %@", [self getDayOfMonthFromComponent:self.dateComponents [indexPath.section] [indexPath.row]], [self getMonthNameFromComponents:self.dateComponents [indexPath.section] [indexPath.row]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
        }

        [self.buttonArray addObject:theLabel];
    }

    return cell;
}
```